# Public_activity how to save changed attributes as paramters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to save the changes on the object as parameters

```
tracked owner: Proc.new{ |controller, model| controller.current_user }, parameters: Proc.new{|controller,model| ????}
```

As I need to check what the user did in this activity. I want to do this on the model level.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following method I have saved the changes to the parameters field.

```
tracked owner: Proc.new { |controller, model| controller.current_user }, params:{ "obj"=> proc {|controller, model_instance| model_instance.changes}}
```

and I have also added a line into activity model for serializing it for returning the hash back from the database.

```
serialize :parameters, Hash
```